# vscode debugging returns "An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug a dotnet react app. "dotnet run" works fine. However, debugging my dotnet react app on vscode returns "conntection refused at `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task<Uri> baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, bool proxy404s)`"

The application I am making has a dotnet core backend and react as the front end which is made possible by microsoft spa services. I have tried many fixes that have worked for others such as upgrading my dotnet-sdk but I still get the issue.

Here are my launch.json configurations

````
{
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/debate.dll",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
            "serverReadyAction": {
                "action": "openExternally",
                "pattern": "^\\s*Now listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"                
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]```


This is my build task

```"tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "process",
            "args": [

                "build",
                "${workspaceFolder}/debate.csproj"
            ],
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
        }
````

In my startup.cs i cannot debug past this line
`spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");`

Here is the error message a recieve

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      events.js:183

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices:Error: events.js:183

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
            throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

And on the browser, I get

````
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask<ValueTuple<HttpConnection, HttpResponseMessage>> creationTask)
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, bool doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered(Task<HttpResponseMessage> sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, bool disposeCts)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task<Uri> baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, bool proxy404s)```

I was able to reproduce the error 'dotnet run' instead of 'sudo donet run'.
````

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the node proccess doesnt end even after I stop debugging. So ending it manually using **killall node** before I start another debugging session stopped producing the error.